# Make CodeIgniter Database query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

Can someone help me to get done this query with Codeigniter Active record  ?:

i have a int array with two values :

```
 $prices =  array( 
       [0] => 23,
       [1] => 98
       );
 how i can make something like : 

return $this->db->query("select * from product where price IN (?)", array(implode(',',$prices))->result();
```

Any help please.

Comment: Sorry, but what i mean by my question is this code don't work for me but just i supposed to do, precisely with `IN` statement

Comment: Check out my answer as I think it will do what you're asking. I haven't used CI in a while so I may be rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested)

```
$query = $this->db->from('product')
                  ->where_in('price', implode(',',$prices))
                  ->get();
```

The [CodeIgniter Active Record docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) are very good so you should definitely read up on it. For instance you'll notice the `select()` method is unecessary since we want all items so `*` is assumed.

Comment: I believe there is no need to `implode` the array `$prices` or else the entire array after `implode` will be considered as a single string. Simply passing the array seems to the syntax, as seen in the example in [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return  $this->db->query("select * from product where price IN ('". implode(',',$prices)->result()."' )");
```